# Remove object name from output header entry with bash and/or sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have an output file that looks like this:

```
Aaa1:Var1 Aaa1:Var2 Bbb2:Var3 Ccc3:Var4 ...
```

I need to find a way to find everything prior to the colon for each entry in the header row. For example:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 ...
```

I want to remove ObjX: from each header entry, but the object names aren't so uniformly named (nor are the variable names) that I can just rip out "Obj*:" or something similar.

The only thing that is certain is that they are separated by spaces (not including a leading space for the first entry) and that the object is separated from the variable by a colon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
read -a headers < file
echo "${headers[@]/*:/}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
sed 's/\b\S*://g' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F ':' -v RS=' |\n' '{print $2}' file
```